# Error in glsEstimate(object, control = control) : computed "gls" fit is singular, rank 19

Tags: r

First time asking in the forums, this time I couldn't find the solutions in other answers.

I'm just starting to learn to use R, so I can't help but think this has a simple solution I'm failing to see.

I'm analyzing the relationship between different insect species (`SP`) and temperature (`T`), explanatory variables
and the area of the femur of the resulting adult (`Femur.area`) response variable.

This is my linear model:

```
ModeloP <- lm(Femur.area ~ T * SP, data=Datos)
```

No error, but when I want to model variance with `gls`,

```
modelo_varPower <- gls(Femur.area ~ T*SP,
                       weights = varPower(),
                       data = Datos
)
```

I get the following errors...

> Error in glsEstimate(object, control = control) : 
>     computed "gls" fit is singular, rank 19

The linear model barely passes the Shapiro test of normality, could this be the issue?

```
Shapiro-Wilk normality test
data:  re
W = 0.98269, p-value = 0.05936
```

Strangely I've run this model using another explanatory variable and had no errors, all I can read in the forums has to do with multiple samplings along a period of time, and thats not my case.
Since the only difference is the response variable I'm uploading and image of how the table looks like in case it helps.

[image]

Comment: How big is your data set? Can you post it somewhere?  Can you show us `summary(Datos)`?

Comment: around 164 lines, here is a link to my data set @BenBolker
[link](https://gofile.io/d/akDpfT)

_> summary(Datos)
      T                  SP                  N          Femur.area   
 Length:152         Length:152         Min.   : 384   Min.   :21408  
 Class :character   Class :character   1st Qu.:1442   1st Qu.:30939  
 Mode  :character   Mode  :character   Median :2168   Median :47727  
 Mean   :2111   Mean   :44967  
 3rd Qu.:2863   3rd Qu.:58184  
 Max.   :3288   Max.   :76906_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some missing cells in your `SP:T` interaction. `lm()` tolerates these (if you look at `coef(lm(Femur.area~SP*T,data=Datos))` you'll see some `NA` values for the missing interactions).  `gls()` does not.  One way to deal with this is to create an interaction variable and drop the missing levels, then fit the model as (effectively) a one-way rather than a two-way ANOVA.   (I called the data `dd` rather than `datos`.)

```
dd3 <- transform(na.omit(dd), SPT=droplevels(interaction(SP,T)))
library(nlme)
gls(Femur.area~SPT,weights=varPower(form=~fitted(.)),data=dd3)
```

If you want the main effects *and* the interaction term *and* the power-law variance that's possible, but it's harder.

Comment: I run in my code
`Datos <- Datos[complete.cases(Datos), ]`
to remove all NA from the dataset, shouldn't that already solve the missing interactions or there is something I'm missing?

Comment: that's fine.  The `NA` values are not in your data set, they're in the *output* of `lm()` (denoting the species/temperature combinations that can't be estimated because they're missing data or confounded with another combination)

Comment: Thanks to your line of code I could recheck and seems that on importing/exporting or generating new data, some SP variables appeared with some letter not in capslock. Fixed that from the data frame and seems to be working now!
Thanks a lot! Your code pinpointed this discrepancy